# Ruby On Rails - Update se hace muy lento al actualizar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Cuando le cargo los parametros que estan en otra tabla acualiza uno por uno[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código, en los parametros tengo un arreglo:

```
@ordenes_servicio.update(ordenes_servicio_params)
```

> parametros

```
def ordenes_servicio_params
  params.require(:ordenes_servicio).permit(:ID,
    :PKTIPO_AUTO, :PKMARCA, :OS_AUX_DESCRIPCION, :OS_AUX_REQTRASLADO, :OS_AUX_NOTAS,:OS_FOLIO_ELECTRONICO,:OS_FALLAMECANICA,
    :ordenes_servicio_precios_attributes => [ :id, :ID, :OS_ID, :selector_servicio,:PKSERVICIO, :OSP_PRECIO, \
      :OSP_CANTIDAD, :OSP_SUBTOTAL, :OSP_TAX, :OSP_TOTAL,:OSP_PRECIOC, :OSP_SUBTOTALC, :OSP_TAXC, :OSP_TOTALC, :_destroy])

end
```

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Puede que no tengas índices en la tabla

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aqui te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Eso es por como funciona el ORM de Rails, ActiveRecord mapea de forma virtual las tablas y las hace un recorrido en profundidad para ir realizando actualizaciones en las dependencias, podrías revisar este articulo sobre realizar algunas optimizaciones https://blog.codeship.com/speed-up-activerecord/ o podrías ejecutar las consultas de forma manual (Es lo mas optimo) o usar alguna Gema que te ayude a construir consultas de forma mas rápida.